# Laravel - uploading to s3 host error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload to Amazon s3, but when I do so I get an error:

> S3Exception in WrappedHttpHandler.php line 192: Error executing
>   "ListObjects" on
>   "https://s3.frankfurt.amazonaws.com/images.football-talents.com?prefix=profile%2F157f0e3656a416.png%2F&max-keys=1&encoding-type=url";
>   AWS HTTP error: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host:
>   s3.frankfurt.amazonaws.com (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

I have checked my bucket details and for the region it `says: Frankfurt`, and I also have a correct bucket name, so I don't know why it is not resolving a host?

Answer (score 1):

The mistake was that even though it only says Frankfurt as a region in my bucket, it needs to be set as `eu-central-1` in the config file.